# Visual Studio 2015: How To Maintain Spacing After Copy Paste

Tags: visual-studio-2015

I align my assignment operators like such:

[image]

However when I copy paste I get this:

[image]

Do you know what setting I can set to have Visual Studio 2015 maintain spacing with a copy-paste?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adjust formatting option to your liking. In particular to disable formattin on paste:

Tools->Options->Text Editor->C#->Formatting -> "Automatically format on paste".

Comment: This works great except for 1 minor caveat. The first line on a multi-line paste is tabbed by 1. Do you know a fix for that as well?

Comment: @Aggressor no. I'm content with default formatting so never needed to look for such option. There are way too many choices :) plus tons more if you use ReSharper. Hope you'll find set you like. (And with copy-paste you can always immediately undo formatting as paste and auto-format are separate undo units).